# can insert data to mysql in php call from node js? WITHOUT EXPRESSJS

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

i am new in `nodejs`

i want create app use `nodejs` and `php`

the scheme like this..

`nodejs`-->id-->`php`(insert data to mysql)

`nodejs` send value id to `php` page (`php` receive data from `nodejs`).in `php` i want to insert data to `mysql`

my question is how i send value to `php` from `nodejs` so `php` can receive the data?
how i achieve this?any tutorial explain about this?

thanks

Comment: Why don't you talk with MySQL directly from Node?

Comment: @bfavaretto : i know node can talk with mysql,but that is not the answer..,i just want send value to php from node...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node side make a post to your php file. Like:

```
var postRequest = {
    host: "mydomain.com",
    path: "/myfile.php?do=insert&field1=somedata",
    port: 80,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  
    }
};
```

and php side recive these stuff like:

```
$_POST['...']
```

Then do db actions.

Heres more info: [node.js POST request fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6221679/node-js-post-request-fails)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

So I guess you essentially are wanting to move data from a node.js server on one running PHP? In that case you will need to use a web request from within node.js to the URL that your PHP instance is running on. I would recommend Mikeal's excellent [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) package.

You can use it like so:

```
var request = require('request');

//so we assume this function is called with some
//string value for id, and some string representing
//the URL for your PHP endpoint, e.g.:
//>sendIdToURL('foo', 'http://mydomain.com/myendpoint.php')
function sendIdToURL(id, url) {
    request(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: id
    }, function(err, response) {
        if(err) throw err;
        else {
            //do something with the response if you want
        }
    });
}
```

Then on the PHP end your `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`, or `file_get_contents("php://input")` will have the value 'foo'.

Does that answer the question? It's an interesting use case that you have to use php for the  mysql connection...